# How can I merge to update two dfs which have same col names?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame that contains a list of emails, some of which are in NA. The dataframe has an ID column and no NA.
The other day I got some data with some new information. It is a data frame with new email information and corresponding IDs.
I am hoping to add this to my email list. At first, I thought that using `full_join()` or `left_join()` would be a good way to do that. But this way, the added email column is recognized as a new column. I don't want to add a new column, I want to update the email column.
Is there a simple solution to accomplish this?
To show this situation in a simple way I generate the following data.

email list:

```
> email_df <- tibble(
+   id = 1:10,
+   email = rnorm(10, 1000, 10)  # Here, each number is an individual e-mail address.
+ )
> email_df[c(1,3,5,7,9), 2] <- NA  # These lines are missing values.
> email_df
# A tibble: 10 x 2
      id email
   <int> <dbl>
 1     1   NA 
 2     2 1000.
 3     3   NA 
 4     4  989.
 5     5   NA 
 6     6 1011.
 7     7   NA 
 8     8 1000.
 9     9   NA 
10    10  987.
```

the new information:

```
> new_infomation <- tibble(
+   id = c(1,3,5,7),
+   email = rnorm(4, 1000, 10)
+ )
> new_infomation
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     id email
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  990.
2     3 1006.
3     5 1007.
4     7 1009.
```

bad solution:

```
> full_join(email_df, new_infomation, by = "id")
# A tibble: 10 x 3
      id email.x email.y
   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1     1     NA     990.
 2     2   1000.     NA 
 3     3     NA    1006.
 4     4    989.     NA 
 5     5     NA    1007.
 6     6   1011.     NA 
 7     7     NA    1009.
 8     8   1000.     NA 
 9     9     NA      NA 
10    10    987.     NA
```

Of course, this data can be fixed as follows, but it seems to me to be too verbose.

```
> full_join(email_df, new_infomation, by = "id") %>% 
+   mutate(
+     email = ifelse(!is.na(email.x), email.x, email.y)
+   ) %>% 
+   select(id,email)
# A tibble: 10 x 2
      id email
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1  990.
 2     2 1000.
 3     3 1006.
 4     4  989.
 5     5 1007.
 6     6 1011.
 7     7 1009.
 8     8 1000.
 9     9   NA 
10    10  987.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rows_update` function from `dplyr` can be used here.

```
library(dplyr)

email_df %>% rows_update(new_infomation, by = 'id')

#      id email
#   <int> <dbl>
# 1     1  984.
# 2     2 1008.
# 3     3  997.
# 4     4  997.
# 5     5  990.
# 6     6 1001.
# 7     7 1006.
# 8     8 1008.
# 9     9   NA 
#10    10 1000.
```